# Able to select "I'm Feeling Lucky" but cannot click it

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to write a simple program to open up chrome, go to Google, and click on "I'm Feeling Lucky." I see that it acts as if the cursor is placed over the icon, but it will not perform a click.

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) \
    .until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "gbqfbb")))
element.click()
```

No errors occur in the code, but it will not click the element.

Comment: Did you try waiting for clickable? Generally, if you are going to click an element, you want to wait for it to be clickable. If you want to interact with it in another way, e.g. pull `.text`, etc., then you can just wait for visible.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find that ID either.

here's what worked for me using **css_selector**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from appium.webdriver.common.mobileby import, By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) \
    .until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By. CSS_SELECTOR, '[name="btnI"][type="submit"]')))[0]
element.click()
```

I suggest to use `visibility_of_any_elements_located` over `visibility_of_element_located`. The reason is that the selector finds two elements. One visible and one that is not.

When using `visibility_of_element_located` it will use find_element and it will get the element that is not visible.

When using `visibility_of_any_elements_located` it will use find_elements and it will get both elements. it will loop through all elements and if one or more are visible it will return it right away.

Answer (score 0):

Where you get that ID? When I visit the site, I don't see an element with that ID. It's possible that Google has some sort of way of manipulating this to make it harder for people to automate this process. It's possible that Google doesn't want you doing this.

Either way, you should be able to select the element by something else:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) \
    .until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By. CSS_SELECTOR, '[jsaction="sf.lck"]')))
element.click()
```

Comment: When I visit the site the button has the same id as listed in the question. Could be somewhat of a coincidence though.

Comment: @QuinnMortimer for me, the ID is different. It's possible that the webdriver is getting a different ID too.

Comment: I see the same ID as in OP's code. Open Chrome, go to google, and put `$$("#gbqfbb")` in the console. It should find 1 `INPUT` element.

Comment: @JeffC see: https://imgur.com/a/NWOpFHw `document.querySelectorAll('#gbqfbb')` also returns an empty `NodeList`. Google's infrastructure is really complicated, it's more than possible that there's more to it.

Comment: try by name... something like //input[contains(@name, 'btnI')]

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='FPdoLc lJ9FBc']//following::input[@class='RNmpXc']")).click();
```